# How can I conditionally validate the presence of an element from a list of allowed child elements?

Tags: xml

I have an xml schema which contains sections and layouts. I have a collection of layouts e.g.

```
<layouts>
    <layout name="wiki" type="page"/>
</layouts>
```

I have sections that refer to the layouts. e.g.

```
<section name="intro-page">
    <allowedLayouts>
        <layout name="wiki" type="page"/>
    </allowedLayouts>
</section>
```

I need to validate that the `layout`s present in `allowedLayouts` are only picked from `<layouts>`
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "link"?

Comment: In the example I gave. I have a list of available layouts, which I define in a layout collection. I have sections which can use layouts. But I have to specify the entire layout element inside the section. How can I add a restriction in the xml file to allow only layouts that are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me.

The secret is to use keys and idrefs.

In the root element, I add the following restrictions.

```
<xs:key name="PK_layout">
    <xs:selector xpath="layouts/layout"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:key>
```

This ensures that the name of the layout cannot be duplicated in the layouts collection.

Here's the restriction on the foreign key in section specified inside the root element.

```
<xs:keyref name="FK_sectionToLayout" refer="PK_layout">
    <xs:selector xpath="sections/section/allowedLayouts/layout"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@layoutid"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Here's how to link to a layout in the layouts collection from a section in the sections collection

```
<xs:element name=section>
...
    <xs:attribute name="layoutid type="xs:IDREF"/>
...
</xs:element>
```

Here's a sample section

```
<section name="intro-page">
    <allowedLayouts>
        <layout layoutid="wiki"/>
    </allowedLayouts>
</section>
```

This ensures that section will only use valid layouts while cross-referencing the layouts collection.